# How can i center the buttons in my navigation bar?

Tags: css

```
<div id="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li id="nav">
            Home
        </li>
        <li id="nav">
            HTML/CSS
        </li>
        <li id="nav">
            PHP/MySQL
        </li>
        <li id="nav">
            Contact
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is all the html i'm currently using for my navigation bar. The CSS is:

```
#bar {
    height: 3px;
    width: auto;
    background: rgb(100,100,100);
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: -10px;

}


#navbar {
background: rgba(125,125,125,0.5);
width: auto;
height: 20px;
padding: 10px;
padding-left: 80px;
margin: -10px;
}


li#nav:hover{
    background: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #FFFFFF;
}

ul {
    list-style-type:  none;
    display: block;
} 

li#nav {
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center; 
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: -26px;
}
```

I can not get the buttons to stay in the center. I've tried display: block inline and block-inline and none of those work like when other people use them. It currently looks like this:

http://i.gyazo.com/ad8ca7626594348dc1141bcbea8079d2.png

I'd like a little bit of space between the buttons but that should be easy with some margins.

Comment: Can you make it a code snippet (Ctrl+M)? Or a http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<style>
html, body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#navbar {
    background: rgba(125, 125, 125, 0.5);
    width: auto;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
li#nav:hover {
    background: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #FFFFFF;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
li#nav {
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}
</style>
<div id="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li id="nav">Home</li>
        <li id="nav">HTML/CSS</li>
        <li id="nav">PHP/MySQL</li>
        <li id="nav">Contact</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Check it out here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vdc4xnc/)

Comment: This worked great, thanks! Can you explain what you did?

Comment: I put `text-align:center` on navbar div to center things. Then i changed from `float: left` to `display: inline` on `li#nav`, since text-align only work for inline elements. Then i removed some padding and margins just messing things up.

Comment: @caeth ID's are unique and you should use classes instead of id's because you can use the same class on multiple elements. -  http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following css:

```
#bar {
    height: 3px;
    width: auto;
    background: rgb(100,100,100);
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: -10px;

}

#navbar {
background: rgba(125,125,125,0.5);
width: auto;
height: 20px;
padding: 10px;
padding-left: 80px;
margin: -10px;
}


li#nav:hover{
    background: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #FFFFFF;
}

ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
} 

li#nav {
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center; 
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top:-10px;
}
```

Here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/b28wsn9p/1/).